# Android Edit text and Button widget appears blurry in tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

HI stackoverflow friends,

On recent days I am facing an issue in android layout. I have a made an app that needs to run on android phones and tablet. So I made independent layouts for phone and tablet as descrided in android developer document. But my edittext and button appears a blurry in tablet but it works perfectly in phones up to 2.3 .My design is same in both.During design time ,graphical layout show the correct as I need. On running on emulator and on actual device it appears as below. But It perfectly ok in phones(2.3).

Tablet layout.

[image: This is my layout appears in tablet]

Phone layout as I need

[image]

I have noticed that when my layout screen becomes large it becomes blurry feel.

I couldn't figure out what mistake happened to me.

**UPDATED**

In my Manifest.xml I have added

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
         android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
     <supports-screens 
                  android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="true" 
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens= "true"
                  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

But no effect.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out my issue. By setting theme in application element 
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme"` in manifest.xml file.

```
<application 

android:label="@string/app_name" 

android:icon="@drawable/logo" 

android:vmSafeMode="false" 

android:theme="@android:style/Theme">
```

Thanks to all for supporting me.

Answer (score 2):

It might be in compatibility mode.  From the documentation,

> "...if your application does not successfully follow the guide to
>   Supporting Multiple Screens, then it might encounter some rendering
>   issues on larger screens."

The manifest needs to be adjusted to disable compatibility mode.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html

Comment: Mel@:Thanks for your great answer,in my manifest I have added In my Manifest.xml I have added 

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
             android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
         <supports-screens 
                      android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="true" 
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens= "true"
                      android:anyDensity="true" />

But no effect.